# Is it true that $L_{f+g}(M)\le L_f(M)+L_g(M)$ if $M$ is a partition on [a,b] and $f, g$ are two bounded functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-sum

Here I have a bit confusion, if $f$ is positive and $g$ is negative, does that mean the total lower sum is $L_f - |L_g|$ or is it the absolute value?

If $f$ and $g$ are both positive, how do you know that $L_{f+g}$ is exactly the sum of $L_f(M)$ and $L_g(M)$?

In addition, what do you need to formally prove this? Any help will be great.

Comment: You should probably explain in your question what $L_f(M)$ means. Not everybody reading your question will be familiar with the notation.

Answer (score 0):

The signs of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not relevant.  Also the lower sum of the sum of functions does not necessarily equal the sum of the lower sums. This only applies to Riemann sums with the same tags.

Note that on any sub-interval $I$ of the partition and $x \in I$,

$$\inf_I f(x) \leqslant f(x),\\ \inf_I g(x) \leqslant g(x).$$

Hence, for every $x \in I$

$$\inf_I f(x)+\inf_I g(x) \leqslant f(x)+ g(x),$$

and

$$\inf_I f(x)+\inf_I g(x) \leqslant \inf_I[f(x)+ g(x)].$$

So it appears the inequality should be reversed:

$$L_f(M) + L_g(M) = \sum_{k=1}^n \inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x)(x_k - x_{k-1}) + \sum_{k=1}^n \inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}g(x)(x_k - x_{k-1}) \\ \leqslant  \sum_{k=1}^n \inf_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}[f(x)+g(x)](x_k - x_{k-1}) = L_{f+g}(M)$$

Comment: Very thorough and reasonable. But I just can't find any real example that counters $L_{f+g}(M)\le L_f(M)+L_g(M)$.

Comment: It is not true for lower sums.  Are you using L to represent a Riemann sum for a tagged partition? See comments above.

Comment: Also can you show me the functions where the min of the sum is less than the sum of mins?

Comment: If the functions are both monotonically increasing or both monotonically decreasing then, trivially, the equality holds but it is not true in general.